# Cannot access org.apache.lucene.index.LeafReaderContext in ElasticSearch 8.8.1

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to update ElasticSearch Version from 7.10 to 8.8.1 in our custom elastic pluggin.
But getting following error during Maven build:

> cannot access org.apache.lucene.index.LeafReaderContext

Any idea how to resolve it and what is alterntive to use lucene classes in ElasticSearch 8.8.1